# Quickly output Session ID within a .JSP?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I would like to quickly output the current session id on a .jsp page for debugging purposes.

Is this possible? Does anyone have a JSP snippet that does this?

Thanks very much!

Edit:
I found what I was looking for:

```
<c:out value="${pageContext.session.id}"/>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have EL enabled in your container, you can do it without the JSTL tag - ie just ${pageContext.session.id}

An alternative for containers without EL:  <%= session.getId() %>